# filter the Json according to string in an array in JSONPATH

Tags: jsonpath

I have a situation where I have json String that has a child as Array that contains only Strings. Is there as way I can get the object reference of the arrays that contains a specific String. 
Example:

```
{ "Books":{  
      "History":[  
         {  
            "badge":"y",
            "Tags":[  
               "Indian","Culture"
            ],
            "ISBN":"xxxxxxx",
            "id":1,
            "name":"Cultures in India"
         },
         {  
            "badge":"y",
            "Tags":[  
               "Pre-historic","Creatures"
            ],
            "ISBN":"xxxxxxx",
            "id":1,
            "name":"Pre-historic Ages"
         }
     ]
  }
}
```

To Achieve:
From the above JSON String, need to get all books in History which contains "Indian" inside the "tags" list.

I am using JSONPATH in my project but If there is other API that can provide similar functionality, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Goessner JSONPath, `$.Books.History[?(@.Tags.indexOf('Indian') != -1)]` as mentioned by Duncan [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30031333/8882940) should work.

If you're using the Jayway Java port (github.com/jayway/JsonPath), then 
`$.Books.History[?(@.Tags[?(@ == 'Indian')] != [])]` or more elegantly, use the `in` operator like this `$.Books.History[?('Indian' in @.Tags)]`. Tried them both [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: For me Tags[?(@ == 'Indian')] != null worked (null instead of []). I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken in C# if anyone may find it useful.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using Goessner JSONPath (http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) the following should work:

```
$.Books.History[?(@.Tags.indexOf('Indian') != -1)]
```

According to the Goessner site, you can use underlying JavaScript inside the `?()` filter.  You can therefore use the JavaScript `indexOf` function to check if your Tags array contains the tag 'Indian'.

See a working example here using this JSONPath query tester:
http://www.jsonquerytool.com/sample/jsonpathfilterbyarraycontents

Comment: This works with the Java port (https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) as well. Tested with version 2.0.0.

Comment: Hey @Duncan, Is it possible to check if any string value in jsonPath repeated, could you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954727/check-if-any-value-in-jsonpath-is-repeated

Comment: @RüdigerSchulz: I tried the exact JSON above with the solution suggested, on Jayway JsonPath, version 2.0.0 and it did NOT work. It does not give an error but it does not return any values. 

On version 2.3.0, it gives an exception, " 'indexOf' are not closed properly", which is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use underscoreJS ? You can get the Indian books like this :

```
var data = {"Books:"....};

var indianBooks = _.filter(data.Books.History, function(book) { return _.contains(book.Tags, "Indian"); })
```

Comment: I would assume OP is using Java (alltough it is not clear)