# Check if any value in jsonPath is repeated

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

I have a jsonPath as below

```
{   "book":
        [ 
            { "category": "reference",
              "author": "Nigel Rees",
              "title": "Sayings of the Century",
              "price": 8.95
            },
            { "category": "fiction",
              "author": "Nigel Rees",
              "title": "Sword of Honour",
              "price": 12.99
            }
]}
```

And Want to check if any author name have got repeated?
I tried

```
$.book[?(@.author=='Nigel Rees')].find(1)
```

But, it always throws an exception  that found nothing, how could I check that the `author='Nigel Rees'` occurrences i.e `author='Nigel Rees'` have a two books?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you are planning on doing if the authors names exists.
If you only want the objects with author of `Nigel Reese` you could use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
    var booksByNigelReese = book.filter( function(book, index) {
        return book.author === 'Nigel Reese'
    })
```

`.filter()` takes a function that takes the book and index, chooes to accept or rejcet the book into a new array depending if the result of the function is `true` or `false`

Comment: Actually I'm using Gatling Scala DSL `.check(jsonPath("$.book[?(@.author=='"+authorName+"')]").find(1))`. I'm trying to validate that `authorName` Should not repeated. I'm interested in count, how many times that string is repeated ?

Comment: Oh, same concept could still hold though. Are you able to filter the array and then check the length of the new array?