# How to extract array element without key?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jayway

I have a json as below. I want a json path expression that checks if [e3] exists in the below json. Can someone help please?

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "error": [
        "[e1]",
        "[e2]",
        "[e3]",
        "[e4]"
    ]
}
```

Comment: yourObj['error']['e3'] !== undefined

Comment: I tried it, Didn't work. I tried it in https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52977857/1065197. I tested using `$[?(@.error[?(@ == '[e3]')] != [])]` and Jayway JsonPath evaluator.

Comment: Yeah Luiggi. That works. It returns the whole json if [e3] is present. Is there a way to return 'yes' or something more specific? Returning [e3] itself is also fine. Thank You.

Comment: That's not supported from JsonPath, you will always receive a json. What you could do is to check if the result json is empty or not.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `Jsonpath` doesn’t always return  json. If the path is definite you can actually cast it to the expected return type. `$.status` and `$.error[2]` returns string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below `JSONPath` will return a list with one element. `Indefinite` paths always returns a list. A path is `indefinite` if it contains an expression - `?(<expression>)`. Refer [What is Returned When?](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when)

```
$.error[?(@ == '[e3]')]
```

[image: Jayway JsonPath]

Comment: `List<String> errorCodes = JsonPath.read(json, "$.error[?(@ == '[e3]')]");`

Comment: That is just what I want. Thank You, Akshay.